# Does Xamarin support Google Maps v3?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin

I'm researching Xamarin to possibly use it for an upcoming project but I need several features from Google Maps v3 and I have looked everywhere and I can't seem to get a definitive answer if Xamarin supports Google Maps v3 so can anyone who knows give me the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Maps **JavaScript** API is "versioned" differently then the **Android** API (and have different APIs). In the past (`v2`) there was a matching reference between the two, most notably in the Android manifest APIKEY v2 reference.

The Google Maps **JavaScript** API:

- 3.28 is the frozen version (February 15, 2016)
- 3.29 is the Release / Reference version
- 3.30 is the current "experimental" version

The Android Google Maps version is tied to Google Play Services as Maps is directly dependent upon Play Services. The developer controls which version to support based upon what version of Google Play Services is installed on the device and possibly requiring the user to update their installed OS versions via the Play store in order to present the Google Map in their app.

The Google Map **Android** API:

- 11.4.0 is the Release version (September 19, 2017)

  - Java Package:

    - `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0`
  - Matching Xamarin version:

    - `id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps" version="57.1104.0-beta1"`

Google Maps Android Releases:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases